# How to find the value of $x+y$ in the following equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $(2x+1)^2+y^2+(y-2x)^2=\frac{1}{3}$, what's the value of $x+y$?

I tried to use an algebraic identity
$(....)^2+(....)^2=0$
but did not succeed.

Comment: There is an implicit context here: $x,y$ are real numbers. (Otherwise, no unique solution exists.)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by expand $(2x+1)^2$ and $(y-2x)^2$ using the binomial theorem.

$(2x+1)^2+y^2+(y-2x)^2 = 4x^2+4x+1+y^2+y^2-4xy+4x^2 = 8x^2+2y^2-4xy+4x+1 = \frac{1}{3}$

Multiplying both sides by $3$ and subtracting $1$ gives

$24x^2+6y^2-12xy+12x+2 = 0$

Adding and subtracting $12y$ and grouping terms

$24x^2+6y^2-12xy+12x+2+12y-12y = 0$

$12x+12y+24x^2+6y^2-12xy-12y+2=0$

$-12(x+y)=24x^2+6y^2-12xy-12y+2$

$x+y = -2x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2-xy+y-\frac{1}{6}$